# How I can to validate MIXED INPUT in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I have an example https://jsfiddle.net/vintkor/b35kxu90/19/
How I can validate **input5** and **select** fields together?
I didn't find this in the official documentation

HTML

```
   <el-form ref="form" :model="form" :rules="rules">

     <el-form-item prop="input5">
       <el-input class="inline-input" placeholder="Please input" v-model="form.input5" style="width: 300px;">
         <el-select required v-model="form.select" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
           <el-option label="Restaurant" value="1"></el-option>
           <el-option label="Order No." value="2"></el-option>
           <el-option label="Tel" value="3"></el-option>
        </el-select>
        <el-button slot="append" icon="search" @click=submitForm('form')></el-button>
      </el-input>
    </el-form-item>
  
  </el-form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean by "validate input5 and select fields together" ? Do you want validation for each field to depend on the value of the other field? Like when the select is "restaurant" then the input should be a string, but when it's "Order No." it should be a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own custom validation:

```
data() {
    var validateInput5 = (rule, value, callback) => {
       if (value === '') {
          callback(new Error('Please enter an input'));
       } else if (value !== this.form.select) {
          callback(new Error('Please select something'));
       } else {
          callback();
       }
    };

    return {
      form: {
        input5: '',
        select: '',
     },
     rules: {
       input5: [
          { validator: validateInput5, trigger: 'blur' }
       ],
     }
  }
},
```